# VBA to C# conversion in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vba, outlook, vsto

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with VSTO. Presently, I am working on modifying the contents of the body through a ribbon button, after the email has been typed.

I am aware the Word Editor is the default editor in Outook 2007. So how can I get the text of the body to perform search and replace operations when using word editor for the inspector window(compose mail window)?

I have a macro code in VBA, which works perfectly fine. I want to convert this code into C sharp which will work when the ribbon button is clicked in compose mail window.

```
Sub ASAtoHyperlinkCompose()

 Dim uiInspector As Outlook.Inspector

 Dim uiObject  As Object

 Dim uiItem   As Outlook.MailItem

 Dim uiDoc   As Word.Document

 Set uiInspector = Application.ActiveInspector

 Set uiObject = uiInspector.CurrentItem

 If uiObject.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" And _

  uiInspector.IsWordMail = True Then

  Set uiItem = uiInspector.CurrentItem

  Set uiDoc = uiInspector.WordEditor

  With uiDoc.Range.Find

   .Text = "ASA^$^$^#^#^#^#^#"

   While .Execute

   .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add .Parent, _

  "http://stack.com=" & .Parent.Text & "outlook2007"

    .Parent.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

   Wend

  End With

  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Outlook's automation and toolkit. This is more or less the same code converted to C#. If nothing else it is a start. There is no C# equivalent With statement FYI.

```
private void ASAtoHyperlinkCompose()
   {                                           
       var uiInspector = Application.ActiveInspector;

       var uiObject = uiInspector.CurrentItem;

       if (uiObject.MessageClass.ToString().Equals("IPM.Note") && uiInspector.IsWordMail)
       {
           var uiItem = uiInspector.CurrentItem;

           var uiDoc = uiInspector.WordEditor;

           uiDoc.Range.Find.Text = "ASA^$^$^#^#^#^#^#";

           while (uiDoc.Range.Find.Execute())
           {
               uiDoc.Range.Find.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add(uiDoc.Range.Find.Parent, string.Format(@"http://stack.com={0}outlook2007", uiDoc.Range.Find.Parent.Text));
               uiDoc.Range.Find.Parent.Collapse(wdCollapseEnd);

           }
       }
   }
```